# How can I filter one attribute in ldapsearch that starts with the same name of another?

Tags: ldap, openldap

In my company's ldap we got two attributes, one is called `cryptodata` and the other `cryptodata;binary`

When I do an ldapsearch command and put `cryptodata` ending the command in order to filter by this attribute only, it brings me both `cryptodata` and `cryptodata;binary` attributes. 
I want it to return only `cryptodata` and not `cryptodata;binary` . 
How can I do this ? Both of these attributes are many lines long, so grep would be cumbersome to use.

Example of the command I use that returns both fields:

```
ldapsearch -h 0.0.0.0 -p 389 -D "cn=sysname,ou=whatever,o=ca,c=country" -b "CN=SOMEONE,OU=AUTHORITHY,OU=COMPANY,OU=TYPE,O=CA,C=COUNTRY" -w "password" dn cryptodata
```

please note that both fields are not the same. So I can't just filter by `cryptodata;binary`

Also this is a large company ldap, so I don't have management over the ldap field structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LDAP you can add so-called descriptions to attribute names separated by semicolon. The interpretation of these descriptions can vary depending on the description.

Thus *cryptodata* and *cryptodata;binary* are not different attributes!

Actually `;binary` is just a transfer type to alter the encoding used when transferring the attribute over-the-wire. Today it is of very limited use (see [RFC 4522](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4522#section-4)) and mainly used when requesting PKI certificate attributes.

If your LDAP server really returns different attribute values for *cryptodata* and *cryptodata;binary* you have to examine which one has the right encoding for your client and deal with at the client side. Do not write simple shell scripts. It's better to use a scripting language like Python/Perl/Ruby whatever and a decent LDAP module for that.

Comment: I see. Will deal with that in a different form. Thanks.